# R opening connection to web API with token and reading jason files

Tags: r

I am trying to connect to Web API with token and read jason files from it using jsonlite

```
library(httr)
library(jsonlite)
Token="xmYeeiLGrHJNaYBWgrMfLbpZOwNgpOAh"
source="https://www.ncdc.noaa.gov/cdo-web/api/v2/%s.json"
GET(source)
POST(source,token = "xmYeeiLGrHJNaYBWgrMfLbpZOwNgpOAh")

jsonFiles=fromJSON(source)
```

but I keep getting this error:

> Error in open.connection(con, "rb") : HTTP error 400.

What could I be doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look here. I adjusted the source since you had an invalid endpoint:

```r
library(httr)
library(jsonlite)

Token <- "xmYeeiLGrHJNaYBWgrMfLbpZOwNgpOAh"
# Fetch all available datasets - https://www.ncdc.noaa.gov/cdo-web/webservices/v2#datasets
source <- "https://www.ncdc.noaa.gov/cdo-web/api/v2/datasets" 
response <- GET(source, add_headers(token = Token))
#POST(source, token = Token) # Not needed
# Not actually fetching all datasets, but rather a list of all datasets
raw <- content(response, as="text")
results <- fromJSON(raw)

# Convert to dataframe/tibble
library(tidyverse)
df <- results$results %>% as_tibble()
head(df)
#> # A tibble: 6 x 6
#>   uid            mindate   maxdate   name             datacoverage id     
#>   <chr>          <chr>     <chr>     <chr>                   <dbl> <chr>  
#> 1 gov.noaa.ncdc… 1763-01-… 2018-08-… Daily Summaries          1    GHCND  
#> 2 gov.noaa.ncdc… 1763-01-… 2018-07-… Global Summary …         1    GSOM   
#> 3 gov.noaa.ncdc… 1763-01-… 2018-01-… Global Summary …         1    GSOY   
#> 4 gov.noaa.ncdc… 1991-06-… 2018-08-… Weather Radar (…         0.95 NEXRAD2
#> 5 gov.noaa.ncdc… 1994-05-… 2018-08-… Weather Radar (…         0.95 NEXRAD3
#> 6 gov.noaa.ncdc… 2010-01-… 2010-01-… Normals Annual/…         1    NORMAL…
```

Created on 2018-08-18 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Related to your original code:
`source="https://www.ncdc.noaa.gov/cdo-web/api/v2/%s.json"`

If this was indeed a valid endpoint (which it isn't), I think what you would want is something like this:

`filename <- "dataset_name"
source <- sprintf("https://www.ncdc.noaa.gov/cdo-web/api/v2/%s.json", filename)`

Comment: Your code works like magic, I guess the problem with m code was the path to the source?

Comment: Thanks! Yes, I couldn't find a valid endpoint in the documentation that looked like yours. I think you are looking to download a single dataset. Once you know the dataset id, you should be able to come up with something similar to my code above - https://www.ncdc.noaa.gov/cdo-web/webservices/v2#data